# Adjoint map of $\Gamma$-space prespectrum

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, loop-spaces

I am looking for a reader-friendly proof of the following theorem:

let $A$ be a special $\Gamma$-space then $\pi_0(A(S^0))$ is a commutative monoid (I have proved up to this), if further it is an abelian group then the adjoint map $t: A(S^0) \to \Omega{BA(S^0)}$ for the structure map $s: \Sigma(A(S^0)) \to BA(S^0)$ is a weak homotopy equivalence

Dan Freed in his [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture19.pdf) theorem 19.41 points to Segal's [paper](http://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/segal-csss.pdf) as reference but I cannot find a proof there (did I miss it?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is proposition 1.4 in Segal's [*Categories and cohomology theories*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938374900226) (a paper I love and I strongly encourage everyone interested in homotopy theory to read).

Comment: Yes!  Have heard of that paper many times and now it is time for me to read it!  Many thanks for pointing that out, Denis!